# JavaScript type arrays in JAVA

Tags: java, javascript

Is it possible to have JavaScript Array show below in JAVA?

```
var myArray = [ [‘2011-1-1’, 2],...]
```

I'm trying to store date and value as a pair in an array. Is there an alternative method in JAVA to do something similar?

Comment: You need to try JSON objects .

Comment: You mean a nested array? Sure all languages have this. Btw, you're not using the right quotes `’ != '`

Comment: Why would you need Javascript arrays in Java, Java has its own arrays.
Make an array of `Date` objects.
Unless you mean to ask how parse JavaScript arrays in Java?

Comment: Use Map in java with key/value pair

Comment: I'm getting data through REST into JAVA, where I do some data manipulation. I wanted to keep the date and integer value together.

Comment: Use a JSON library such as Jackson or Gson, then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guess you are talking about keeping/accessing JSON format in Java. You can achieve that using a library like Gson to parse the response into a JsonArray like so,

```
JsonArray yourArray = new JsonParser()
                          .parse("[[\"2012-14-03\", 2]]")
                          .getAsJsonArray();
// Access your array like so - yourArray.get(0).getAsString();
// yourArray.get(0).getAsInt() etc
```

Gson Library link - https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Does this help?

Comment: Uh, why on earth go through a parsed String? Just build `JsonElement`s (although Jackson does that better)

Comment: I think the data is obtained from a REST call, which will be a string at the end of the day. Will not be possible to build `JsonElement`s from that, without parsing one way or the other.