# how get return value from node js to android?

Tags: android, node.js, get

I create android apps as client and node as server, i got problem when i request value from android to node, i use this code in android to communicate with node js

```
String xResult = getRequestJSON("http://mydomain.com:8888");
public String getRequestJSON(String Url){

       String sret="";
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(Url);
        try{
          HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
          sret =requestJSON(response);

        }catch(Exception ex){
        }
        return sret;
    }


    public static String requestJSON(HttpResponse response){
        String result = "";
        try{
            InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                str.append(line + "\n");
            }
            in.close();
            result = str.toString();
        }catch(Exception ex){
            result = "Error";
        }
        return result; 
    }
```

and i got result like this in node.

```
[{"posid":"P0S6f50b314b2c279a2083cb0ef821ccb4d20140218120720","id_a":"ltv@ltv.com","gambar_a":"6f50b314b2c279a2083cb0ef821ccb4d.jpg","user":"lutfi soe","pwaktu":"2014-02-18T05:07:20.000Z","posnya":"test dr android","plat":-7.983757710988161,"plong":112.6549243927002,"pjenis":"I","vote":0}]
```

my question is,how i receive json like that in android ?and parse to string?

thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11393206

Answer (score 0):

If you are receiving `Json` string in proper format then you can use `JSON` jar to parse this json.

You can get a tutorial for `JSON` parsing [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is more on how to parse and access the result in java[read Android].

Here is a solution that could help [JavaScript type arrays in JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22497518/javascript-type-arrays-in-java/22497758#22497758)

```
JsonArray yourArray = new JsonParser()
                      .parse("[[\"2012-14-03\", 2]]")
                      .getAsJsonArray();
// Access your array like so - yourArray.get(0).getAsString();
// yourArray.get(0).getAsInt() etc
```

The above is using a library called [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

P.S: I just plagiarized my own answer. Not sure what criteria to use to mark this question as a duplicate