# I have a json object. I want to access in java service. I am trying to parse it

Tags: java, javascript, json

I am using import **net.sf.json.JSONObject**

My object is like this:

```
[{
    "courseId": "AUTO_CAD",
    "strDate": "02-04-2012"
 }, {
    "courseId": "CNC_PROG",
    "strDate": "03-04-2012"
}]
```

Please help me how to access this in java service

//The code that i have tried.

```
List<JSONObject> jsonList = new ArrayList<JSONObject>(); 
jsonList = (List<JSONObject>) context.get("courseData"); // courseDate is my json object
JSONObject obj = jsonList.get(0); 
Debug.log("courseStartDate ="+ obj.getJSONObject("courseId"));
```

//Using this gives me the following error. org.ofbiz.webapp.event.EventHandlerException: Service invocation error (java.lang.String cannot be cast to net.sf.json.JSONObject)

Comment: what do u mean by java service.. webservice ?

Comment: What have you tried so far, can you show your code and tell us why it's not working?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript type arrays in JAVA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22497518/javascript-type-arrays-in-java)

Comment: Yeah, Its a web service.

Comment: based on your error below, it seems like context.get("courseData") returns a list of string, not jsonObject. You can convert these strings via JSONObject.fromObject(list.get(i))

Comment: @Robbie I think you are right. printing context.get("courseData") give me {object Object],[object Object}. printing (context.get("courseData")).get(0) give me object Object],[object Object. Now printing ** JSONObject.fromObject(courseList.get(0))** gives me following error: **(A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 1 of object Object],[object Object) **

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have not tested yet the code, but worth a try:

```
JSONArray courses = new JSONArray(json);

JSONObject first = courses.getJSONObject(0); //Or access in a loop using courses.length()
Debug.log("CourseID: "+ first.getString("courseId"));
```

Comment: Using this gives me the following error: javolution.util.FastList cannot be cast to net.sf.json.JSONArray.

Comment: printing context.get("courseData") give me {object Object],[object Object}. printing (context.get("courseData")).get(0) give me object Object],[object Object. Now printing ** JSONObject.fromObject(courseList.get(0))** gives me following error: **(A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 1 of object Object],[object Object).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
JSONObject json = (JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON(jsonTxt);
System.out.println(pilot.getString("aKey"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have an ArrayList yourObject

```
for (int i = 0; i < yourObject.size(); i++) { 
 System.out.println(yourObject.get(i).getCourseId());
 System.out.println(yourObject.get(i).getStrDate());
}
```

Comment: It is not really as simple as you might think :P In Java you have to parse each piece of data individually using a JSON library.

Comment: @Jari I have imported net.sf.json.JSONObject. How can I use this to parse each piece of data. Any example that you can give. would be great.

Comment: I thought he is able to let the code do the marshalling of the object with something like 
public class YourObjectList extends ArrayList<YourObject> { }

And directly get the YourObjectList from the requestbody instead of getting the jsonobject